# What is the difference between passing a function and array as an AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Both of these work, but what is the actual difference between each implementation? I'm sure there is a logical reasoning behind each method, and I wish to be enlightened.

```
angular.module('app').controller('GeneralCtrl', 
    function($scope, $location, exampleService) {
        $scope.variable = exampleService.getExampleVariable();
    }        
);

angular.module('app').controller('GeneralCtrl', 
    ['$scope', '$location', 'exampleService', function($scope, $location, exampleService) {
        $scope.variable = exampleService.getExampleVariable();
    }]
);
```

What is the actual difference between these? Where would you use them differently? Why?

**Answer:** Turns out the latter is minification safe as minifiers rename parameter names, so dependencies cannot be inferred from their names, and so must be annotated.

Comment: The difference lies in minification.

Comment: Is that the only difference?

Comment: Read DI http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: AFAIK the latter is minification safe.

Answer (score 4):

This is what Angular calls "inline notation" for dependency injection (see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di for a whole lot of detail).

In the example you gave, the `ng-controller` directive is actually doing the work behind the scenes, of hooking up `$scope`, `$location`, and `exampleService` into the variables you're providing to that first `function`. It's doing this by default based on variable names (that is, it assumes that a variable called `$scope` is asking for the `$scope` dependency).

That said, when you minify your code, the variable names get chopped down also (ie, `$scope` might become `a`). When that happens, Angular now doesn't know what you meant by the variables anymore.

One option is to add

```
GeneralCtl.$inject('$scope', '$location', 'exampleService')
```

Another is to provide those strings like you did in the second example. This makes sure that even if the variable names get changed around, you're telling Angular what they were *supposed* to represent, and it knows how to set them properly.